# Laravel DB updated 2 row even 1 id given

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know what's wrong with my code, i want to update 1 row of my DB, but instead it's updated 2 row at once, i'm using ajax post to update the data

ajax query :

```
$('#tolak').on('click', function() {
                const id = $(this).attr('data-id')
                const name = $(this).attr('data-name')
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Konfirmasi',
                    text: `Apakah anda yakin akan menolak form pendaftaran driver ${name}`,
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ya, tolak!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Batal',
                }).then((result) => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ route('admin.verifDriver') }}',
                            type: 'ajax',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: {
                                id: id,
                                status: 2,
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data)
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Sukses!',
                                    `Berhasil tolak pendaftaran ${name}`,
                                    'success'
                                )
                                fetchData()
                                Swal.hideLoading()
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                Swal.hideLoading()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
```

And here's the controller

```
public function verif(Request $req)
    {
        DB::table('drivers')
            ->where('id', $req->id)
            ->update([
                'status' => $req->status
            ]);
    }
```

it's just a simple code, i have done it before on the other project but it works, i don't know what's wrong with this code.

EDIT

---

Here is my full blade code

```
@extends('admin.layout.app')
@section('content')
    <div x-data="{ showModal: false }">
        <div class="font-bold text-2xl text-primary-admin mb-8">Form Driver</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row gap-4 w-full mb-4 justify-between">
            <div class="flex flex-row gap-4">
                {{-- Modal Tambah Driver --}}
                <div x-data="{ showModalTambah: false }">
                    <button type="button" @click="showModalTambah = !showModalTambah"
                        class="bg-primary-admin hover:bg-primary-admin-hover rounded-lg text-white py-2 px-5 font-bold transform transition-all ease-linear duration-100">Tambah
                        <span class="mdi mdi-plus-thick"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div x-show="showModalTambah"
                        class="fixed text-primary-admin flex pt-40  justify-center overflow-auto z-50 bg-black bg-opacity-40 top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-60"
                        x-transition:enter="transition ease duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
                        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease duration-300"
                        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div x-show="showModalTambah" class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-2xl p-6 sm:w-1/2 mx-10 mb-auto"
                            @click.away="showModalTambah = false"
                            x-transition:enter="transition ease duration-150 transform"
                            x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90 translate-y-1"
                            x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100 translate-y-0"
                            x-transition:leave="transition ease duration-150 transform"
                            x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 scale-100 translate-y-0"
                            x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 scale-90 translate-y-1">

                            TES
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="filter">
                    Show
                    <select id="perPage" onchange="setPerPage()"
                        class="rounded-lg shadow-lg border-none outline-none focus:ring-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-transparent">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="0">All</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Cari Data" id="search"
                    class="rounded-lg outline-none border-none focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-primary-admin transform transition-all ease-in-out duration-100 shadow-lg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="w-full mb-4">
            <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                <table class="w-full z-0 text-primary-admin" id="driverTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr
                            class="font-semibold text-sm text-white bg-primary-admin uppercase border-b border-primary-admin">
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">No</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Nama</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Email</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">TTL</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Alamat</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Tipe Kendaraan</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">No. Kendaraan</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Warna</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Status</th>
                            <th class="px-4 py-3">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="bg-white text-sm">
                        <div id="loading"
                            class="flex flex-col items-center w-full z-10 absolute bg-primary-white bg-opacity-30">
                            <img src="{{ asset('loading.gif') }}" />
                        </div>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div id="table-footer" class="flex justify-between">
            <div id="data-info"></div>
            <div id="data-paging" class="flex flex-row gap-2"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->

        <!-- Modal Background -->
        <div x-show="showModal"
            class="fixed text-primary-admin flex pt-40  justify-center overflow-auto z-50 bg-black bg-opacity-40 top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-60"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
            x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease duration-300"
            x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div x-show="showModal" class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-2xl p-6 sm:w-1/2 mx-10 mb-auto"
                @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="transition ease duration-150 transform"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90 translate-y-1"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100 translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease duration-150 transform"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 scale-100 translate-y-0"
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 scale-90 translate-y-1">
                <div class="w-full flex justify-end">
                    <button @click="showModal = !showModal"><span
                            class="mdi mdi-close-thick text-primary-admin"></span></button>
                </div>

                <div id="modalLoading" class="flex w-full justify-center">
                    <img src="{{ asset('loading.gif') }}" />
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="hidden w-full flex-col text-lg" hidden>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Nama</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="nama">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Email</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="email">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">TTL</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="ttl">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Alamat</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="alamat">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Tipe Kendaraan</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="tipe_kendaraan">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Merk</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="Merk">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Tipe</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="tipe">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">Warna</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="warna">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">No. Kendaraan</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="w-8/12" id="no_kendaraan">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">No. KTP</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="flex flex-row justify-between w-8/12" id="no_ktp">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">No. STNK</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="flex flex-row justify-between w-8/12" id="no_stnk">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-3">
                        <div class="w-3/12 font-bold">No. SIM</div>
                        <div class="w-1/12 font-bold">:</div>
                        <div class="flex flex-row justify-between w-8/12" id="no_sim">Data</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Buttons -->
                    <div id="buttonGroupVerif" class="text-right space-x-5 mt-5">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="tolak" data-id="" data-name=""
                            class="px-4 py-2 text-sm bg-white rounded-xl border transition-colors duration-150 ease-linear border-gray-200 text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 font-bold hover:bg-red-500 hover:text-white focus:bg-indigo-50 focus:text-indigo">Tolak</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="setuju" data-id="" data-name=""
                            class="px-4 py-2 text-sm bg-white rounded-xl border-2 transition-colors duration-150 ease-linear border-primary-admin text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 font-bold hover:bg-primary-admin hover:text-white focus:bg-indigo-50 focus:text-indigo">Verifikasi</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('script')
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var isLoading = true;
        var page = 1;
        var perPage = 10;
        var pageLimit;
        var search = ''

        function paging(e) {
            page = parseInt(e)
            fetchData()
        }

        function previousPage() {
            if (page > 1) {
                page--
                fetchData()
            }
        }

        function nextPage() {
            if (page < pageLimit) {
                page++
                fetchData()
            }
        }

        toggleLoading()
        fetchData()

        function setPerPage() {
            page = 1
            perPage = $('#perPage').val()
            fetchData()
        }

        function toggleLoading() {
            if (isLoading) {
                $('#loading').removeClass('hidden')
            } else {
                $('#loading').addClass('hidden')
            }
        }

        function callData(e) {
            $('#modalLoading').show()
            $('#modalBody').addClass('hidden')
            $('#modalBody').removeClass('flex')
            $.ajax({
                url: `{{ url('admin/form-driver/show') }}/${e}`,
                method: 'GET',
                type: 'ajax',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#modalLoading').hide()
                    $('#modalBody').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#modalBody').addClass('flex')
                    $('#nama').html(data.driver.name)
                    $('#email').html(data.driver.email)
                    $('#ttl').html(data.driver.birth_date)
                    $('#alamat').html(data.driver.address)
                    $('#tipe_kendaraan').html((data.driver.vehicle_type === 'car') ? 'Mobil' : 'Motor')
                    $('#merk').html(data.driver.brand)
                    $('#tipe').html(data.driver.type)
                    $('#warna').html(data.driver.color)
                    $('#no_kendaraan').html(data.driver.vehicle_number)
                    $('#no_ktp').html(data.driver.ktp_number +
                        ` <a href="${data.photo_ktp}" target="_blank"><span class="text-blue-500 text-xl hover:text-blue-300">Lihat KTP <span class="mdi mdi-open-in-new"></span></span></a>`
                    )
                    $('#no_sim').html(data.driver.sim_number +
                        ` <a href="${data.photo_sim}" target="_blank"><span class="text-blue-500 text-xl hover:text-blue-300">Lihat SIM <span class="mdi mdi-open-in-new"></span></span></a>`
                    )
                    $('#no_stnk').html(data.driver.stnk_number +
                        ` <a href="${data.photo_stnk}" target="_blank"><span class="text-blue-500 text-xl hover:text-blue-300">Lihat STNK <span class="mdi mdi-open-in-new"></span></span></a>`
                    );
                    (data.driver.status == 0) ? $('#buttonGroupVerif').show(): $('#buttonGroupVerif').hide()
                    $('#tolak').attr('data-id', data.driver.id)
                    $('#tolak').attr('data-name', data.driver.name)
                    $('#setuju').attr('data-id', data.driver.id)
                    $('#setuju').attr('data-name', data.driver.name)
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            })
        }

        function fetchData() {
            isLoading = true
            toggleLoading()
            $.ajax({
                'url': `{{ url('admin/getDriverJSON') }}?page=${page}&perPage=${perPage}&search=${search}`,
                'type': 'GET',
                'dataType': 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    isLoading = false;
                    toggleLoading()
                    pageLimit = data.last_page
                    var html = '';
                    var i = 1;
                    var no = (data.current_page == 1) ? 1 : (((data.current_page - 1) * perPage) + 1)
                    data.data.forEach(e => {
                        html +=
                            `<tr>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${no}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${e.name}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${e.email}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${e.birth_date}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${e.address}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${(e.vehicle_type === 'car') ? 'Mobil' : 'Motor'}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${e.vehicle_number}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${e.color}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border">${(e.status == 0 ? 'Belum Diverifikasi' : (e.status == 1) ? 'Diterima' : 'Ditolak')}</td>
                                    <td class="px-4 py-3 border flex flex-row justify-center">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="view" @click="showModal = !showModal; callData(${e.id})"><span class="mdi mdi-eye text-xl"></span></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>`
                        no++
                    });
                    $('#driverTable tbody').html(html)
                    var nav = ''
                    data.links.forEach((e, index) => {
                        var active = (e.active) ? 'bg-primary-admin text-white' :
                            'bg-white text-primary-admin hover:bg-primary-admin hover:text-white'
                        var disabled = 'bg-white text-gray-300 cursor-default'
                        nav +=
                            `<button class="px-4 py-3 ${(e.url == null) ? disabled : active} rounded-md shadow-md transform transition-all ease-in-out duration-100" onClick="${index == 0 ? 'previousPage()' : index == (data.links.length - 1) ? 'nextPage()' : `paging(${e.url.split("=")[1]})`}">${e.label}</button>`
                    });
                    $('#data-paging').html(nav)

                    $('#data-info').html(
                        `<span>Showing ${data.from} to ${data.to} from ${data.total} data</span>`
                    )
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            })
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            function debounce(callback, wait) {
                let timeout;
                return (...args) => {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        callback.apply(this, args);
                    }, wait);
                };
            }

            $('#search').on('input', debounce((e) => {
                search = e.target.value
                fetchData()
            }, 500))

            function toggleModal() {
                $('#driverModal').toggleClass('hidden')
                $('#driverModal').toggleClass('flex')
            }

            $('#close-modal').on('click', function() {
                toggleModal()
            })
            $('#modal-bg').on('click', function() {
                toggleModal()
            })

            $('#tolak').on('click', function() {
                const id = $(this).attr('data-id')
                const name = $(this).attr('data-name')
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Konfirmasi',
                    text: `Apakah anda yakin akan menolak form pendaftaran driver ${name}`,
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ya, tolak!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Batal',
                }).then((result) => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ route('admin.verifDriver') }}',
                            type: 'ajax',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: {
                                id: id,
                                status: 2,
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log('sukses update');
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Sukses!',
                                    `Berhasil tolak pendaftaran ${name}`,
                                    'success'
                                )
                                fetchData()
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                console.log(e)
                                Swal.hideLoading()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })

            $('#setuju').on('click', function() {
                const id = $(this).attr('data-id')
                const name = $(this).attr('data-name')
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Konfirmasi',
                    text: `Apakah anda yakin akan menerima form pendaftaran driver ${name}`,
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ya, terima!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Batal',
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ route('admin.verifDriver') }}',
                            type: 'ajax',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: {
                                'id': id,
                                'status': 1,
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log('sukses update');
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Sukses!',
                                    `Berhasil menerima pendaftaran ${name}`,
                                    'success'
                                )
                                fetchData()
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                console.log(e)
                                Swal.hideLoading()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: what you send as an Id and witch ids change their status?

Comment: @amirhoseinhadi it happened very randomly, in this case, i have 4 data with id `1, 2, 3, 4`, when i update the status for id 1, sometimes the updated ids is id 1 and 2, or 1 and 3

Comment: use an alert function to check exactly how many times the ajax is running. if there is only one id sent, there is no way for it to update mutiple DIFFERENT ids.

Comment: @Mashtan i don't know how, after i put alert function on ajax success, it only update 1 data, but when i try to put console.log it back to update 2 data

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN  can you show full blade file code so we can see how you fetch id in ajax from dom

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN that means your ajax is sending the id multiple times. the issue is not your controller. do you have any records in console.log as to what id it is sending? check if it shows 2 id sent.

Comment: @JohnLobo i've edit my question to add the full blade

Comment: @Mashtan i'm afraid that's not what happen, bcs on the Network tab, it only sent 1 request

Answer (score 1):

Select single data, modify it and save like

```
public function verif(Request $req)
{
    $model=Driver::where('id', $req->id)->first();
    $model->status=$req->status;
    $model->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update with eloquent model instead of DB.

```
public function verif(Request $req)
{
    Driver::where('id', $req->id)
        ->update([
            'status' => $req->status
        ]);
}
```

Dont forget to import Driver namespace.

Comment: this will make no difference at all. He already has a condition set for id. Eloquent itself will not change that.

Comment: I know but from DB query its not works as expected then i suggest to try with model update.